# jQuery hover and other mouse move events doesn't get triggered on Firefox when mousedown started from an inputbox

Tags: jquery

Im customizing [Bootstrap Token Field](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) for a project, im extending it to support highlighting the tokens, then pressing delete or backspace to remove the selected tokens. I was able to implement it, but only on other browsers except for Firefox. Because in Firefox, when you started mousedown on an input-box, and dragged to other elements, the mousemove event doesnt get triggered.

I created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zuzgo77/3/) to show this.

```
     <script>
         $( ".token" ).hover(function(){
             $(this).css('background-color','red');
         });
     </script>
     <style>
         .token {
              background-color: lightblue;
              width:            100px;
              height:           20px;
              display:          inline-block;
         }
     </style>
     <body>
         <div class="token">Token 1</div>
         <div class="token">Token 2</div>
         <div class="token">Token 3</div>
         <input type="text">
     </body>
```

Try to mouse down on the input box on JS Fiddle and drag to the left tokens, in other browsers the tokens to the left will get highlighted, but not in Firefox. The reason for an input box is that theres an input box in the right of the Token-field and thats the natural movement of the user when highlighting, to start from the input box. Highlighting when not starting from input box works ok. Chrome and other browsers seems to be a bit flexible on this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who got the same problem, this is the workaround i come up with, if i detect that there's no input yet (it means also that the users intention is not to select the text on the input box) is to call e.preventDefault() to cancel the mousedown event so the hover will highlight the tokens. I created an updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zuzgo77/9/) to illustrate this.

```
    $( "#inputtext" ).mousedown(function(e){
        if($( "#inputtext" ).val() === ""){
            e.preventDefault();
            $( "#inputtext" ).focus();
        }
    });
```

The call to focus() will place the cursor back to the input box as calling preventDefault() will cancel the mouse click and will prevent the cursor appearing, focus() places the cursor back.